# iCloud Entitlements setting in "XCode > Target A > Summary" improperly affecting other targets

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, entitlements

I have two targets in my app, one has iCloud support and the other does not.

In my target A summary, with iCloud support, I have Entitlements check, Enable iCloud checked, identifiers, etc. It all works.

On my target B, everything becomes automatically filled out the same as target A! When I uncheck anything, it's becomes unchecked on target A. E.g., I'll uncheck "Enable iCloud" for target B, then when I view target A again, all my iCloud stuff is gone.

Any ideas? Anybody else have a similar issue?

I'm using XCode 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating the `Entitlements-Target[1|2].plist` file for each target, re-adding them to the project and pointing each `info-Target[1|2].plist` at the new entitlements file and it stuck. Good old XCode.